# Dynamic names for setState in react -native

Tags: react-native, fetch-api

```
 constructor(props){
    super(props);

this.state = {
  services:
    [
        {
            "name": "",
            "icon": require('./home-icon1.png')
        },
        {
            "name": "",
            "icon": require('./home-icon2.png')
        },
        {
            "name": "",
            "icon": require('./home-icon3.png')
        },
        {
            "name": "",
            "icon": require('./home-icon4.png')
        },

      ]
};


}
componentWillMount(){
               fetch('link.com', {
                method: 'GET',

              }).then((response) => response.json())
                    .then((responseJson) => {

                    if(responseJson.message === "List of Services"){
                      var length = responseJson.result.length.toString();
                      ToastAndroid.show(responseJson.message, ToastAndroid.LONG);
                      for(var i = 0 ; i < length ; i++){

                        const services = [...this.state.services];
                        services[i].name =  responseJson.result[i].Service.service_name
                        this.setState({ services : services });
                        //this.setState({[services[i].name] : responseJson.result[0].Service.service_name})
                      }
                       Alert.alert(services.length);
                    }
                    else{
                      Alert.alert("Cant Connect toSErber");
                    }


                    }).catch((error) => {
                      console.error(error);
                    });
```

}

basically what i am trying to do is fetch some data from server and then using that data i am changing state of services which is state of component.But the syntax which i am using to setState for the services is wrong.How can i setState of services correctly after fetching data from server

Comment: perhaps it would be better use Redux https://redux.js.org/

Answer (score 0):

you're over-engineering it.  try this:

1. set this.state.services to an empty array = [];
2. when you fetch the data, do this:

   const services = [...this.state.services];
   const serviceData = responseJson.result;

   serviceData.map((service, index) => {
     services[index]['name'] = service.Service.service_name;
     services[index]['icon'] = iconComponent;
   });

   this.setState({ services });

Comment: services[index][name] = service.Service.service_name; line gives me error.It tells services[index][name] "name" is undefined

Comment: Sorry, put quotes around name in the brackets. Without them its looking for a variable which doesn't exist and is thus undefined.